# Problema com EntityFramework - An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker

Tags: entity-framework, asp

Tenho um projeto onde um `dropdownlist` é carregado com as seguintes instruções:

```
var lista = entities.prato.OrderBy(x => x.nome).ToList();

combo.DataTextField = "nome";
combo.DataValueField = "id";
combo.DataSource = lista;
combo.DataBind();
```

Depois preciso recuperar o item do `dropdownlist` e utilizar para criação de um registro, para recuperar o item eu utilizo a seguinte linha:

```
ingrediente i = entities.ingrediente.Find (Convert.ToInt32(combo.SelectedItem.Value));
```

Quando tempo salvar o registro da seguinte forma:

```
ingrediente_prato ip = new ingrediente_prato();
ip.prato = (prato)Session["pratoSelecionado"];
ip.ingrediente = i;
entities.ingrediente_prato.Add(ip);
entities.SaveChanges();
```

é retornado o seguinte erro:

> An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker

Alguém tem alguma sugestão?

Comment: Tem que postar o código inteiro !!! as classes também talvez nem precise recuperar o ingrediente!

Answer (score 0):

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace Refeitorio
{
    public partial class Prato : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

```
    private bancodadosEntities entities = new bancodadosEntities();
    private List<ingrediente> ingredientes;



    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack) {
            carregarGrid();
            carregaListIngredientes();
            entities.ingrediente_prato.OrderBy(x => x.ingrediente.nome).ToList();
        }
    }

    private void limpar()
    {
        txtID.Text = string.Empty;
        txtNome.Text = string.Empty;
    }

    private void carregarGrid()
    {
        var lista = entities.prato.OrderBy(x => x.nome).ToList();
        grid.DataSource = lista;
        grid.DataBind();
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        limpar();
    }

    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtID.Text == string.Empty)
        {
            prato p = new prato();
            p.nome = txtNome.Text;
            entities.prato.Add(p);
            entities.SaveChanges();
            limpar();
            carregarGrid();
        }
    }

    private void carregaListIngredientes()
    {
        var lista = entities.prato.OrderBy(x => x.nome).ToList();

        var lista2 = entities.prato.OrderBy(x => x.nome).ToList();
        combo.DataTextField = "nome";
        combo.DataValueField = "id";
        combo.DataSource = lista;
        combo.DataBind();

    }

    protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var a = combo.Items.FindByValue(combo.SelectedValue);

        ingrediente i = entities.ingrediente.Find (Convert.ToInt32(combo.SelectedItem.Value));

        entities.Entry(i);
        ingrediente_prato ip = new ingrediente_prato();
        ip.prato = (prato)Session["pratoSelecionado"];
        ip.ingrediente = i;
        ip.quantidade = Convert.ToInt32(txtQtdIngredientes.Text);
        entities.ingrediente_prato.Add(ip);
        entities.SaveChanges();
        carregaListIngredientes();
        combo.SelectedValue = null;
        txtQtdIngredientes.Text = string.Empty;
    }

    private void carregarGridIngredientes()
    {
        gridIngredientes.DataSource = ingredientes;
        gridIngredientes.DataBind();
    }

    protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName.Equals("Ingredientes"))
        {
            int linha = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
            var value = Convert.ToInt32(grid.Rows[linha].Cells[0].Text.ToString());
            Session["pratoSelecionado"] = entities.prato.Find(value);
            ModalPopupExtender1.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

}